# What is a good php class for SMTP email?

Tags: php, smtp

Recommendations please (from experience ideally, but anything is useful).
Searching Google gives me too many choices, and I would like to know if there is a good one people use.

Comment: Depends very very much on your use case and what you mean by "good". Do you want a clean API? You want a certain feature? Or easy configuration? Or the ability to handle large file attachments? Or a certain character set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com) class. It allow to send email as from your own domain and from remote account (ex.: gmail.com). Attachments, HTML messages, embedded images and many more features. Enjoy! :)

Comment: I don't get it why this answer is the best... chris asked about incoming email class (POP/IMAP), while PHPMailer is for sending emails (SMTP).

Answer (score 2):

Pear has some mail classes:

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

Answer (score 2):

I have been very happy with [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) - its quite powerful and has batch sending features.

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer is a great class for sending messages using SMTP.  However, as far as I know it does not support incoming mail. You need a class that supports pop3 and/or imap.

This class supports imap and pop3:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html).

If you are not using a framework you could get that piece of code from the source.

Answer (score 0):

I like [XpertMailer](http://www.xpertmailer.com/) and it has also a good MIME class in case you need manipulate/create/modify body emails

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a php imap class is what you are looking for. Something like the [imap.class.php in mortar](http://code.google.com/p/mortar/source/browse/trunk/system/library/Imap.class.php) or [php-imap](http://code.google.com/p/php-imap/).